# Unable to share data between AngularJS controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I had seen the [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) video on [sharing data between controllers](http://youtu.be/HXpHV5gWgyk), but couldn't get it to work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('QData', function () {
    return 'hello'
});

function QCtrl($scope, $http, QData) {
  $scope.foo = QData;
}

QCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData'];

function YCtrl($scope, $http, QData) {
  $scope.bar = QData;
}

YCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData'];
```

See code (with additional bootstrap view) [running on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ihtLa69RaCpulFJJZpRU)

Comment: What isn't working? 'hello' shows up in the results in that plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an intermediate object and it's property directly.

[Like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/wj2mTZLbWfS0vC3QRAJA?p=preview).

Comment: Plunker not available

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('QData', function () {
    return 'hello' 
});

function ParentCtrl($scope, $http, QData) {   
    $scope.foo = 'My data'; 
}

QCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData'];

function QCtrl($scope, $http, QData) {  }

QCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData'];

function YCtrl($scope, $http, QData) { }

YCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because your factory is returning a string. And strings behave differently from objects in js (iirc, they are wrapped up into objects when they are treated as them, otherwise they are primitives). For example

```
var a = 'hello';
var b = a;
a.x = 1;
console.log(b.x) //undefined

var a = {x: 1}; var b=a; a.y = 1; console.log(b.y); //1
```

basically, it'd be better if you work with objects, like here : http://plnkr.co/edit/zqCPn9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If your service is changing QData, and not a property within QData - Angular loses track of the object reference, and the other controllers don't know what's going on.

Tweaked your code and added a use of $timeout to simulate something like an $http request updating your QData. Forked your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zawBRj) - but relevant JS code below.

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('QData', function () {
    return { text: 'hello' } ;
});

function QCtrl($scope, $http, QData, $rootScope) {
  $scope.foo = QData;
}

QCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData', '$rootScope'];

function YCtrl($scope, $http, QData, $rootScope,$timeout) {
  $scope.bar = QData;
  $rootScope.globe = 5;
  $timeout(function()
  {
    QData.text = "Test!"
  },5000);

}

YCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'QData', '$rootScope','$timeout'];
```